# flutter firebase dynamic link dont work some devices

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

```
static initDynamic(BuildContext context) async {
final instanceLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
print(instanceLink);

if (instanceLink != null) {
  final Uri idLink = instanceLink.link;
  Map<String, dynamic> params = idLink.queryParameters;
  print(params);

  if (params["id"] != null) {
    context.toNamed(FromDynamicLinkScreen.routeName,
        arguments: params["id"]);
  }
}
```

I call it in my MyApp class, it works on the emulator and on my own device, but it does not work on my client and his friends, it loads on the screen, the overlay appears and does not apply to the application